# capturing particular string and values from a php string

Tags: php

I have a variable in php that has the following value:

```
var $line="'PHYSICAL':3.8,'ORGANIZATIONAL':4,'TECHNICAL':2.9";
```

From that line variable, I want to extract each word and values in php, so basically I want something like below:

```
var $word1=PHYSICAL;
var $word1value=3.8;
var $word2=ORGANIZATIONAL;
var $word2value=4;
var $word3=TECHNICAL;
var $word3value=2.9;
```

I want to capture all the words and values separately in different variables, so that later I can process them. Can anyone please assist me on this. Thanks.

Comment: can't you just use arrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is with [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php). You can use the `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` flag to enable capturing the word without the surrounding quotes, and `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` to remove the empty values that arise from this particular split pattern.

```
$line="'PHYSICAL':3.8,'ORGANIZATIONAL':4,'TECHNICAL':2.9"; 
$array = preg_split("/'([^']+)':|,/", $line, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => PHYSICAL
    [1] => 3.8
    [2] => ORGANIZATIONAL
    [3] => 4
    [4] => TECHNICAL
    [5] => 2.9
)
```

You can then post-process the array (for example using [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)) to produce something which might be more useful:

```
$newarray = array_combine(array_filter($array, function ($i) { return !($i % 2); }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY),
                          array_filter($array, function ($i) { return $i % 2; }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY));
print_r($newarray);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [PHYSICAL] => 3.8
    [ORGANIZATIONAL] => 4
    [TECHNICAL] => 2.9
)
```

If you really want the individual variables you can do this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i += 2) {
    ${'word' . intdiv($i+2, 2)} = $array[$i];
    ${'word' . intdiv($i+2, 2) . 'value'} = $array[$i+1];
}
echo "word1 = $word1\n";
echo "word1value = $word1value\n";
echo "word2 = $word2\n";
echo "word2value = $word2value\n";
echo "word3 = $word3\n";
echo "word3value = $word3value\n";
```

Output:

```
word1 = PHYSICAL
word1value = 3.8
word2 = ORGANIZATIONAL
word2value = 4
word3 = TECHNICAL
word3value = 2.9
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much. This works perfectly fine. I appreciate your help.

Comment: That's great, glad to help. I've also (since I was in the process of typing when you accepted the answer) added a way to get the individual variables you described in your question.